# URL Change - Check if Post Exists Before 404

Tags: 404-error, rewrite-rules, iis

We had a custom CMS with URLs such as `/adele`, `/slayer`, `/beastie-boys` but now they have the structure `/artist/adele`, `/artist/slayer`, `/artist/beastie-boys` (a custom post type)

Obviously when people visit the original links, they get a 404. Is there a way/what's the best way to check whether whether the post exists in the new format first before throwing out a 404 error? There's 80k or so artists in the database.

We're on IIS so could make use of a `rewritemap` but it'll probably be too massive

Comment: .htaccess redirect?

Comment: On IIS? Nope!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkArtist() {
    $page = get_page_by_path($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/',OBJECT,'artist');

    if($page){
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
        header("Location: /artist".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'checkArtist' );
```

I add a custom hook using [wp](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) which as the article says:

> This hook is one effective place to perform any high-level filtering
>   or validation, following queries, but before WordPress does any
>   routing, processing, or handling.

The function then uses [get_page_by_path](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) to retrieve a page given its path. The path is took from the URL using PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. If it exists for that particular post type then I do a 301 redirect.

Comment: Please add an explanation of what your code does and how it works. Your answer has already ben flagged as low quality due to the lack of info. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry for causing so much distress to the community - I will amend as necessary.

Comment: No problem. ;-) Always nice when someone comes back to answer his own question. Just remember to accept it as well as soon as the restriction is lifted